# Dynamically add a prop to a ReactJS object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this object created as follows

```
let comp = <MyComponent
  msg="hello"
>
```

Now I want to add another property foo="bar" to object comp. I could always have something like

```
let comp = <MyComponent
  msg="hello"
  foo={this.state.barOrNoBar}
>
```

But I am getting an array of these objects from another piece of code and cannot add foo there. I just want to add this property only as needed. What is the right way to do this (other than doing a DOM findNode and using setAttribute)?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a functional component like this:

```
const MyComp = ({barOrNone = null}) =>
  <MyComponent msg="hello" foo={barOrNone} />;
```

And then, to use it:

```
<MyComp barOrNone={this.state.barOrNone} />
```